# BSimagePicker selected images to e-mail attachment

Tags: ios, swift, image, email, attachment

I have created a simple app that needs to send some pictures to a specific e-mail. Already got following working

Take picture, Select picture (bsimagepicker), Send e-mail button that creates e-mail to specific e-mail adress.

Now i want to add the selected images with bsimagepicker to the e-mail as an attachment. But now when i press done the app forgets the selected images. This is the code i am using for BSimagepicker.

```
@IBAction func showImagePicker(sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
    vc.maxNumberOfSelections = 10

    bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
        select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Cancel: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Finish: \(assets)")
        }, completion: nil)


@IBAction func showCustomImagePicker(sender: UIButton) {
let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
vc.maxNumberOfSelections = 10
vc.takePhotoIcon = UIImage(named: "chat")

vc.albumButton.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
vc.cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
vc.doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
vc.selectionCharacter = "✓"
vc.selectionFillColor = UIColor.grayColor()
vc.selectionStrokeColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
vc.selectionShadowColor = UIColor.redColor()
vc.selectionTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
vc.cellsPerRow = {(verticalSize: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass, horizontalSize: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass) -> Int in
    switch (verticalSize, horizontalSize) {
    case (.Compact, .Regular): // iPhone5-6 portrait
        return 2
    case (.Compact, .Compact): // iPhone5-6 landscape
        return 2
    case (.Regular, .Regular): // iPad portrait/landscape
        return 3
    default:
        return 2
    }
}

bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Selected: \(asset)")
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Deselected: \(asset)")
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Cancel: \(assets)")
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Finish: \(assets)")
    }, completion: nil)
```

and for email i am using following code:

```
mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["jvanhattem@it-serve.nl"])
mailComposerVC.setSubject("Mail vanuit PicMail")
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Onderstaand de doorgestuurde informatie", isHTML: false)

if let image = imageView.image {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "image/jpg", fileName: "image")
}
```